# C# WPF - Completely Remove Object and ALL Children

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Grid which I am utilizing as a sort of "popup" control. This control is dynamically created for each specific item clicked.

Please note, this control has layers of other controls with children, other grids and stackpanels.

To close it I have a "Cancel" button, currently I am casting the parent object in the EventHandler and using `[castedobject].Children.Remove(popup)` to close the object.

However, when I click another "parent" when the program goes to re-create the Grid window I am getting lots of Exceptions because the same objects are trying to get re-assigned as children even though they are "currently assigned".

My question is this: What command do I use (when closing) to permanently remove all reciprocal children and their associations? This seems like something that would be standard in a dynamic control environment. I am sure I am missing something simple, but I've tried the methods I have found while searching Stack Overflow and Google, but I'm still reaching the same Exceptions.

```
colorCancelBtn.Click += delegate (object source, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            container.Children.Clear();
            Grid temp = (Grid)dataObject.FindName("colorPicker");
            Grid parent = (Grid)temp.Parent;
            parent.Children.Remove(temp);
            dataObject.UnregisterName("colorPicker");
        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove all of the Grid's Children first:

```
SomeGrid.Children.Clear();
```

You can then remove the grid without retaining any other object references.

Comment: Robert, this is exactly what I was trying to do. But when the object gets re-created I have an assignment line `rgbFields.Children.Add(redUpDown);` it keeps giving me the Exception that this is already assigned. This is the only place this object is created and used.

Comment: It goes without saying that there's almost certainly a better way to do this.  Perhaps a legitimate dialog box?

Comment: Not familiar with "legitimate" dialog boxes. This is an object which purposely overlays a portion of my window to prohibit access while in use. I would want it to be a child element of sorts rather than an independent Window. It is a very intricate tool with nearly 1000 lines of code and multiple classes comprising it. Not sure how easy it would be to port over to something new if necessary.

Comment: Material Design in Xaml has a flyout that is modal.  But any modal form would do.

Comment: I'll try to look into this tonight to measure its feasibility. I will be sure to report back in with what I figure out. Thanks!

Comment: So, I've been reading a bit. This may have something to do with my creating this as a static class. (I wanted a way to quick reference commands using "using" instead of constantly instantiating. Re-working.

Comment: Yep.  I knew you were doing something under the hood you weren't telling us about.

Comment: Yeah, the static method / class was the problem. My reference to the object seems convoluted - perhaps you can help me with that on another question path. But, changing everything by removing 'static', changing my instantiation and then making new reference calls has everything working now! Thanks for all of the help, Robert!